# set minDate and maxDate using semantic-ui-calender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, calendar, semantic-ui

Anyone already used semantic ui calendar? 
I got stuck, how can i set the min and max time to 11:00 PM - 6:00 AM.

```
let today = new Date();
let set_date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
let set_next_date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 1);


let min = new Date(set_date.setHours(23,0,0,0));
let max = new Date(set_next_date.setHours(6,0,0,0));

startTime.calendar({
    type: 'time',
    minDate: min,
    maxDate: max,
    onChange(date, text, mode){
        self.updateStartTime(text)
    },
})

endTime.calendar({
    type: 'time',
    minDate: min,
    maxDate: max,
    startCalendar: startTime,
    onChange(date, text, mode){
        self.updateEndTime(text)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create `date` instances to set `hours` for them like what you did, just do like me and you will have what you wanted.

Define 2 new variables and use `setHours` method to change their hours:

```
var minDate = new Date();
var maxDate = new Date();
minDate.setHours(6);
maxDate.setHours(23);
```

and initialize your `Semantic-UI Calendar` like below:

```
startTime.calendar({
    type: 'time',
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    onChange(date, text, mode){
        self.updateStartTime(text)
    },
})

endTime.calendar({
    type: 'time',
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    startCalendar: startTime,
    onChange(date, text, mode){
        self.updateEndTime(text)
    }
})
```

I also provided you an example on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ali_bahrami/ka52oo7s/1/